# gradle refuse to sync even after downloading from their site

Tags: android

I tried to sync my gradle in android studio and it showed me this error even after I tried to sync it locally, still the same error:

Error:BUG!

> exception in phase 'class generation' in source unit
>   'ijinit0_8gov8jl8pmdtxuu0gk1mcw4af' unsupported Target MODULE

Comment: try to change the gradle version inside build.gradle

Comment: try invalidate cache and restart

Comment: How do I invalidate cache

Answer (score 0):

What Gradle and Java versions are you using?

Try downgrading them & delete the `build` and `.gradle` folders in your project directory